# HP Printer not working on lubuntu, when going to print, printer appears in printers, but it is unable to connect

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, printing

I have the HP Laser MFP 135a printer, when going to print, printer appears in the printer options, but either it loads infinitely, or it gives unknown error message.

I have tried downloading and running with sudo from terminal the printer drivers from HP
(https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laser-mfp-130-printer-series/24494378/model/24494379), but I have no idea how to see is installation was successful, and no apparent changes appear. I have also tried using HPLIP, but it seems as if it is an unsupported version.

I am currently using Lubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04

I have tried cheching the USB connection, and have tried running it on windows, and the same cable works. Any ideas on how to get it running, even if the scanner does not work?

Comment: you can install your printer in wifi mode,i did the entire wifi install from my printer no need to touch the pc at all during this install,it will be a driverless install but the printer will work just fine.

Comment: I would try that, but my printer has no WiFi capability....